# Why int a; a = std::max(a, x) doesn't emit "uninitialized" warnings

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings, static-analysis

Consider the following code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{{1, 2, 3}};
    int a;

    std::cout << a << std::endl;    // 1

    for (const int x : v) {
        a = std::max(a, x);         // 2
    }

    std::cout << a << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

As modern compilers grew and now keep a watchful eye over dumb programmer mistakes, they track unitialized variables. This C++ code however, confuses them. So far, I get following results:

```
                        (1)      (2)
g++ 5.3.1
clang++ 3.7              ✔
Solaris Studio 12.5      ✔
```

As you can see, CLang and solstudio can detect only case (1) and ignore case (2), while g++ is ignoring both. Is there a complication to detect it in case (2)? Why g++ is so bad at this?

Compiler options I used:

```
$ g++-5 -std=c++11 -Wall -Wpedantic -pedantic -Wextra \
         -Wuninitialized -Wmaybe-uninitialized aisa.cpp
$ clang++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wpedantic -pedantic -Wextra -Wuninitialized aisa.cpp
$ CC -std=c++11 -xprevise aisa.cpp
```

Comment: Consider filing a feature request on both gcc and clang's bug trackers - trivial situations like this one could probably be detected with additional logic

Comment: What happens if you remove the first example?  Do clang or Solaris Studio warn about the unitialized variable then?

Comment: You may also get better warnings if you crank up the optimization level.

Comment: @MartinBonner: g++-5 detects (1) with `-O2`, and removing case (1) doesn't help to make (2) catchable (actually I added case (1) after I've noticed that compiler failed to detect (2))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: Both compilers only diagnose the first offense, that is they only report the first uninitialized use of `a`. So to get a warning for the second one, we need to remove that first line:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{{1, 2, 3}};
    int a;

    for (const int x : v) {
        a = std::max(a, x);         // 2
    }

    std::cout << a << std::endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Now we see two unrelated compiler quirks: **clang** does not include `-Wconditional-uninitialized` in `-Wall` and `-Wextra`. If you enable that, you *do* get a warning at the `std::cout` because it potentially prints an uninitialized variable.

**gcc** on the other hand only tracks uninitialized variables when the optimizer is enabled, probably to speed up compilation of debug builds. With `-O2 -Wall`, gcc 6 throws a warning in both cases, though without pinpointing the location as exactly as clang does in the second case. (gcc <= 5.3 does not warn about the second case as you observed, so it seems that was implemented recently.)

So TL;DR: You did not invoke your compilers right.

Comment: "First offense" meaning the first occurrence of a specific warning, right? Not a warning in general?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Yes. Feel free to edit if you can state that more clearly.

Comment: Yeah, I've used g++ 5. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 12):

`std::max` takes its arguments by `const &`, while the streaming operator `<<` for `int`s takes the `int` by value. Passing an uninitialised object by reference is legal: for example, if the function just takes its address, all is well. Therefore, warning on passing `a` to `std::max` could easily be a false positive.

Comment: It indeed would make sense not to warn if it concerns a reference. But this is a const reference. I'd think this would be a situation in which the compiler actually could warn, as there is no way you could initialize an object passed over by a const reference.

Comment: @MarTijn What if the sole purpose of the function was to take a `const *` to the object and use it as a map key? You can do this from a `const &`, and you can do this even from an uninitialised object.

Comment: @MarTijn: If the function saves the address of the object, then something later can initialize the variable. (Or the function can use the address alone as some sort of unique tag).

Comment: Valid points! TBH I never use constructs like this, so a compiler option would perhaps be preferable.

Comment: You point seems valid, but `int mymax(int a, int b) { return (a>b)?a:b; }` doesn't help much, case (2) still not covered

Comment: @myaut OK, *that's* strange. I would expect the compilers to catch that one.